# Magento command line putty

Tags: magento2.3, command-line, setup-upgrade, static-content-deploy, putty

I have Magento 2.3.
I have moved the website to another server but all command [php bin/magento setup:upgrade
, php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f, and any other command
]
on command putty command line . gives result

```
"check-requirements": false,
    "dump-autoload": false,
    "stub": "php-cs-fixer",
    "compactors": [
        "KevinGH\\Box\\Compactor\\Json",
        "KevinGH\\Box\\Com[klinikomcom@37-148-208-177 public_html]$
```

Comment: Need to check the permission of files and directories

Comment: how to check this

Comment: you can check with ll command